# How to execute a callback method instead of an anonymous method?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, callback

The following example works, but how can I change it so that instead of executing the anonymous method, it executes my existing callback method `OnCreateOfferComplete()`?

```
using System;

namespace TestCallBack89393
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OfferManager offerManager = new OfferManager();
            offerManager.CreateOffer("test", () => Console.WriteLine("finished."));

            //offerManager.CreateOffer("test", OnCreateOfferComplete ); 
            //above line gives error: an object reference is required 
            //for a non-static field...



            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private void OnCreateOfferComplete()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finished");
        }
    }


    public class OfferManager
    {

        public void CreateOffer(string idCode, Action onComplete)
        {
            if (onComplete != null)
                onComplete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make method OnCreateOfferComplete static. This should sove your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make OnCreateOfferComplete method **static**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your method `OnCreateOfferComplete()` needs to be `static`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling CreateOffer from a static method (OnCreateOfferComplete is an instance method).

In this case, just declare your `OnCreateOfferComplete` method static.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be static:

```
private static void OnCreateOfferComplete()
{
    Console.WriteLine("finished");
}
```

... because you are calling it from the static `Main` method.